# How to deal with long parameter lists in `New(...` functions

Tags: go

Say I have a localised struct called `MyStruct` with the following body:

```golang
struct MyStruct {
  myField1 string
  myField2 string
  myField3 string
  ...
  myFieldN string
}
```

And a function which instantiates new `MyStruct`s for external callers:

```golang
func NewMyStruct(myField1, myField2, myField3, ..., myFieldN string) MyStruct {
  return MyStruct{
    myField1: myField1,
    myField2: myField2,
    myField3: myField3,
    ...
    myFieldN: myFieldN,
  }
}
```

Question: **How would I best deal with the scenario of there being just too many fields within the struct resulting in a `NewMyStruct(...` function with *way* too many parameters?** Is there any best practice to mitigate this issue? As of now, I have several functions like this in my codebase:

```golang
func NewSuperStruct(myField1, myField2, myField3, myField4, myField5, myField6, myField7, myField8, myField9, myField10, myField11, myField12, myField13, myField14, myField15, myField16, myField17, myField18, myField19, myField20, myField21, myField22) ...
```

But it's not necessarily that the structs themselves are nonsensical in the sense that the properties/fields don't belong within, in my application they do make sense, the structs are just too large, that's all.

Comment: You could export the fields and have the client code set them directly instead of using a `NewXyz` function. If unexported fields are a requirement you could declare an analogous `XyzParams` struct with the same but exported fields and use that as the single parameter of the `NewXyz` func.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say just don't have the `New` func:

```
struct MyStruct {
  myField1 string
  myField2 string
  myField3 string
}

val := MyStruct{
    myField1: "one",
    myField2: "two",
    myField3: "three",
}
```

If unexported fields need to be set from another package, use some kind of options or config:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Exported   string
    unexported string
}

type MyStructOptions struct {
    Exported   string
    Unexported string
}

func NewMyStruct(opts MyStructOptions) *MyStruct {
    return &MyStruct{
        Exported: opts.Exported,
        unexported: opts.Unexported,
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to initialize after setting default values, create an `Init()` method that does the setup after you define your struct instances.

Answer (score 3):

Personally (obviously depending on the goal of the struct) I am a big fan of functional options:

```golang
type MyStructOpts func(*MyStruct)

func WithField1(field1 string) MyStructOps {
  return func(m *MyStruct) {
    m.myField1 = field1
  }
}

func New(opts ...MyStructOpts) *MyStruct {
  m := MyStruct{
    myField1: "someDefaultIfneeded",
  }

  for _, opt := range opts {
    opt(&m)
  }

  return &m
}
```

which can be used as follows:

```golang
New(
  WithField1("someString"),
  ...
)
```

This has a couple of benefits:

- Callers of new do not need to worry about the order
- Passing values is explicit with field name, which means you won't mix up Field1 & Field2
- You have the ability to pass different defaults to `MyStruct` in case callers don't pass `WithField1`
- Adding more fields doesn't lead to having to update all callers of `New`